# How to set dimension (width) in a div box in this situation

Tags: html

I want to set the width (in pixels) of the orange box.

You can see my page on this: [live link](http://jsfiddle.net/MPC/wm754s90/)

```
<div align="center" class="copyright" style="border: thin solid #F48C13"><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="http://192.168.1.100/cgi-bin/class/login.cgi"><strong>Accesso a MpcPanel</strong></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define [`width property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) in your stylesheet for the class ***copyright***

```
.copyright {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Ex.: http://jsfiddle.net/wm754s90/3/

---

***Edit***:
For [`Inline style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2) <sup>*(that's without modify the css file, and including the style directly in the element)*</sup>
The `style attribute` of the `div.copyright` need to be edited.

Just add `width property` alongside to `border`.

```
<div align="center" class="copyright" style="width: 100px; border: thin solid #F48C13;">
    <!-- /* div content */ -->
</div>
```

You can add as many as you want *(semicolon separated)* but keep in mind the *readability of the code* (for that are external CSS files, [among many other benefits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS))
I will recommended to you (if you can of course) to create your own `css file` and include there all the modifications you want.  Will be a [good starting point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) to learn `css` and how it's work.

***Edit <sup>2</sup>***:
Worth to mention that both properties (width & border) might conflict.
Width prop. do not include the border size.
Ex.

```
.copyright {
    width: 100px;
    border: thin solid #F48C13;
}

---------------------
| ----------------- |
| |               | |
| |  div content  | |
| |               | |
| ----------------- |
---------------------
  |               |
  |<------------->|    -----> A) div width = 100px
|                   |
| |               | |
<->               <->  -----> B) div border size = 1px
   \             /       (the size you enter is for each side)
     border size        ("thin" in border size is equal to 1px)
|                   |
|                   |
|<----------------->|  -----> total/final div width = 102px
                                 B + A + B
                                1 + 100 + 1 = 102px
       or use 98px as width...  1 +  98 + 1 = 100px
```

Please refer to [this `box-sizing` article](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) for a better and more accurate explanation (including how to avoid/solution)

Comment: great! it works perfect!Thanks a lot!! Do you think it's posible to do it without editing the CSS file and editing only the HTML code?

Comment: Of course, that's call `inline style`.. one sec. and I will edit the answer.

Comment: thank youvery much for your help and for the information! Now I have a lot of things to study :)

I have done a little change for center the div, with your advice: http://jsfiddle.net/MPC/wm754s90/5/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to make the border of the orange box to be thicker? If so, you would change the border CSS property "thin" to a pixel value, like so:

```
style="border: 4px solid #F48C13"
```

If not, I apologise, I could not comment yet to ask this clarification.

Comment: no, sorry. I want to set the width of the orange box. I have edited the first message so it's much clear. Sorry